Why does the negation of TMIN behave differently for int and char in C?
I'm learning about two's complement and wanted to see what the negation of TMIN (the minimum value for a signed type) is. I wrote the following code for int:
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = -2147483648;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    printf("Size of int: %zu bytes\n", sizeof(int));

    if (i < 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", -i);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}

The output is as expected:
-2147483648
Size of int: 4 bytes
-2147483648
This indicates that the negation of -2147483648 is still -2147483648.
However, when I tried this with char, the behavior was different:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char i = -128;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    printf("Size of int: %zu bytes\n", sizeof(char));

    if (i < 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", -i);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}

The output was:
-128
Size of int: 1 byte
128
I'm using Clang on a Macbook M1.
Why does the negation of -128 for char result in 128 instead of the -128 I was expecting? Is it a compiler problem or a special feature of char?

I've been bitten by this before, it's a "quirk" for INT_MIN. It is the only value where x == -x (except for 0, of course).  Using two's complement arithmetic, -x is: ~x + 1 Since INT_MIN is 0x80000000, then ~x is 0x7FFFFFFF. ~x + 1 is 0x7FFFFFFF + 1, which is 0x80000000. This is INT_MIN This is true for all int on two's complement architectures (virtually all machines in existence that are not in museums).

Notice that the first program very likely has undefined behaviour.

See also Implicit type promotion rules

-2147483648 is not an int on systems with 32-bit int values.  It's not even a single token.  It's the long (or long long) value 2147483648 that's then negated using the unary - operator.  The long (or long long) value is then assigned to int i when it's initialized.
